# Finding the sum of matching components in two lists

Tags: python, list, sum

I have two lists:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

And I need to be able to find the sum of the nth terms from both lists i.e. 1+6, 2+7, 3+8 etc

Could someone please tell me how to refer to items in both lists at the same time?

I read somewhere that I could do Sum = a[i] + b[i] but I'm not convinced on how that would work.

Comment: Have a look at [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) and add a little list comprehension magic.

Comment: duplicate of [Python tuple operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497885/python-tuple-operations) and many, many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the lists will be the same length, you could do this:

```
AB = [A[i] + B[i] for i in range(len(A))]
```

In Python 2, you might want to use `xrange` instead of `range` if your lists are quite large.  I think that's an [explicit, simple, readable, obvious way](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) to do it, but some might differ.

If the lists might be different lengths, you have to decide how you want to handle the extra elements.  Let's say you want to ignore the extra elements of whichever list is longer.  Here are three ways to do it:

```
AB = [A[i] + B[i] for i in range(min(len(A), len(B)))]

AB = map(sum, zip(A, B))

AB = [a + b for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

The downside of using `zip` is that it will allocate a list of tuples, which can be a lot of memory if your lists are already large.  Using `for i in xrange` with subscripting won't allocate all that memory, or you can use `itertools.izip`:

```
import itertools
AB = map(sum, itertools.izip(A, B))
```

If you instead want to pretend the shorter list is padded with zeros, using `itertools.izip_longest` is the shortest answer:

```
import itertools
AB = map(sum, itertools.izip_longest(A, B, fillvalue=0))
```

or

```
import itertools
AB = [a + b for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(A, B, fillvalue=0)]
```

Comment: This will raise `IndexError` if `len(A) > len(B)`.

Comment: This isn't the Pythonic way to do it.  Sorry.

Comment: @TimPietzcker in the situations I am using it len(A) = len(B) for every case, but I appreciate the heads up :)

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Do you mean this will not work? I am confused as it worked for me.

Comment: Using zip() is preferred over approaches using indexes.  The latter is normal for C and Java.  The former is the Python way.  Also, as Tim points out, zip() is designed to handle mismatched sequence lengths.

Comment: Yes. This is unpythonic, this answer.

Answer (score 15):

```
>>> import operator
>>> map(operator.add, A, B)
[7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

just to demonstrate Pythons elegance :-)

Comment: well, this shows python's versatility, because list-comprehensions are far more elegant :-)

Comment: Yeah, you are right: I was more thinking of easy readability: "map" the function "add" to list "A" and "B".

Comment: This fails if A and B are of different lengths. Using zip inside of a list comprehension works well.

Answer (score 13):

Use a list comprehension and `zip`:

```
[a + b for (a,b) in zip(A,B)]
```

Are these questions homework? Or self-study?

Comment: Self study which I can then apply to homework, the question posted on here is an easier version, however the 'homework' isn't assessed as I'm at university.

Answer (score 0):

Although Jazz's solution works for 2 lists, what if you have more than 2 lists?  Here's a solution:

```
def apply_elementwise_function(elements_in_iterables, function):
    elementwise_function = lambda x, y: itertools.imap(function, itertools.izip(x, y))
    return reduce(elementwise_function, elements_in_iterables)

a = b = c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(apply_elementwise_function([a, b, c], sum))
[3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi You can try this too:

```
>>>a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>>b=[6,7,8,9,10]
>>>c=[]
>>>for i in range(0,5):
    c.append(a[i]+b[i])
>>> c
[7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```