# Pre-calculating the values of a dictionary with tuple as its value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have the following code example where I am creating a dictionary `result` for each `id` with a tuple of 2 numbers for its value.

```
# populate the ids list (contents of the current directory which is for a speicif id name)
ids_list = [filename for filename in glob('*' + .txt)

def some_numerical_calc(filename):
    # calculates and returns some number as string
def size_of_file(filename):
    # calculates and returns size number as string

def count_stuff(id, filename):
    result = { id: (some_numerical_calc(filename), size_of_file(filename)) }

for id in ids_list:
    for f in files_list:
        count_stuff(id, f)
```

The idea is that I will eventually aggregate all these dictionary key-value pairs under one dictionary (perhaps this parts needs redesigning..).

The problem I am dealing is for cases where the `files_list` of a specific `id` is greater than 1; in these cases I would like every 2 numbers inside the tuple for each `filename` to be added with the previous numbers for that same `filename`.

> As an **example**,
>
> `ids_list = ['001', '002', '003']`
>
> where for `id='001'` it has 
>   `files_list=['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']`
>
> and if
>
> `some_numerical_calc('file1.txt')` gives `10` and
>   `size_of_file('file1.txt')` gives `80`,
>
> `some_numerical_calc('file2.txt')` gives `150` and
>   `size_of_file('file2.txt')` gives `35`,
>
> `some_numerical_calc('file3.txt')` gives `30` and
>   `size_of_file('file3.txt')` gives `120`,
>
> **then**, I would expect the output for `id='001'` to be `result = { '001': (190, 235) }`

I know that [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) are immutable. I am struggling to come up with an implementation to pre-compute the 2 numbers for all files for each id and then create its specific dictionary entry. Alternatively, perhaps I should remove the tuples structure -even though I was hoping to use [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) and store the 2 numbers in a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (?). Any suggestions are would be much appreciated.

Hoping for an efficient and pythonic suggestions.

Comment: use a list, change the values while you are using it, cast every value to a namedtuple when you are done.  Or alternatively you could use `sum(some_numerical_calc(f) for f in file_list), sum(size_of_file(f) for f in file_list)` and then use that as the two values in the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is you've organized your code badly.  You're creating your dictionary too early.

Consider if you reorganized it something like this:

```
def count_stuff(id, filename):
    return (some_numerical_calc(filename), size_of_file(filename))

for id in ids_list:
    nums = 0
    sizes = 0
    for f in files_list:
        num, size = count_stuff(id, f)
        nums += num
        sizes += sizes
    result = { id: (nums, sizes) }
```

Now your dictionary is created after you've aggregated your data.

Answer (score 0):

To create a tuple that contains sums, you can do something like this*:

```
result[id] = (sum(some_numerical_calc(filename) for filename in files_list),
              sum(size_of_file(filename) for filename in files_list))
```

But just as a heads up, using your current code, this would store the same tuple value in the dict for all of your `id` keys. You don't currently have any way of associating a particular `files_list` with a particular `id`.

*If you only want to iterate once through `files_list` instead of twice, you can adapt one of the answers from here: [Python element-wise tuple operations like sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497885/python-element-wise-tuple-operations-like-sum).

Answer (score 0):

You could try mixing map and sum:

```
resultDict = {}

for id in ids_list:
    resultDict[id] = (sum(map(some_numerical_calc(files_list[id]))), sum(map(size_of_file(files_list[id]))))
```

Edit:

A more detailed example given your particular situation. Some parts will be described in comments in angle brackets.

```
#<Get list of ids as strings>
files_list = {} #Initialize the files dictionary.

for id in ids_list:
    #<Switch to directory based on id>
    files_list[id] = [filename for filename in glob('*' + .txt)]

def some_numerical_calc(filename):
    # calculates and returns some number as string
def size_of_file(filename):
    # calculates and returns size number as string

result_dict = {} #Init results.

for id in ids_list:
    resultDict[id] = (sum(map(some_numerical_calc(files_list[id]))), sum(map(size_of_file(files_list[id]))))
```

Comment: Trying to understand your answer which I find fascinating as an idea. I do not get the `files_list[id]` part. I mean, what will a list return when provided an index which happens to be the key of an unrelated dictionary? Perhaps  if you could add a working example?

Comment: Your explanation seemed to indicate that the files_list was a two-dimensional data set. That is, each id had its own set of files. So, files list would look something like: `files_list = {'001': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'], '002': ['file4.txt', 'file5.txt'], '003': ['file6.txt']}`. So, `files_list[id]` would yield the list of files associated with the given id.

Comment: Apologies if I did not make clearer; no the `files_list` is list of filenames for a specific `id`. Every `id` has its own `files_list`. Like the contents of a folder. Do you think this elegant `sum` & `map` combo could be implemented now?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include how files_list is populated?

Comment: Your code uses `for id in ids_list: for f in files_list:` That uses the same `files_list` variable for every id, so I assumed it was a two-dimensional data set.

Comment: I see what caused the confusion. I edited the question to (hopefully) provide what was missing.

Comment: It took me a while but it does make sense. Thanks for adapting it to demonstrate the use of `map`, even though changing the `files_list` is not an option for me, it is still a very good example.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things strange about your code, for one, you are creating a new dictionary every time you call count_stuff, but never doing anything with it or return it. From the question it seems like you want everything added to one dictionary.

Something like this might work better:

```
def some_numerical_calc(filename):
    # calculates and returns some number as string
def size_of_file(filename):
    # calculates and returns size number as string

def count_stuff(id, file_list):
    some_number = 0
    size = 0
    for filename in file_list:
        some_number += some_numerical_calc(filename)
        size += size_of_file(filename)
    return (some_number, size) 

results = {}
for id in ids_list:
    results[id] = count_stuff(id, file_list))
print results
```

Comment: You are right. Failed to clarify that; I intend to have all dictionary under on dictionary which will hold `id` as keys and the numbers as values. (modified question to mention this)