# Vector Class Adding

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've defined a class for n-dimensional vectors with:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, v):
        if len(v)==0: self.v = (0,0)
        else: self.v = v
```

and one of my functions (add) within the class isn't returning the values I would like it to. Currently I have it defined as:

```
for i in range(self.dim()):
    newvector.append(self[i+1] + other[i+1])
return Vector
```

and I also tried:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    for i in range(len(self)):
        added = tuple( a + b for a, b in zip(self, other) )
    return Vector(*added)
```

but this returns and Unsupported Operand Type error.

The test I'd like it to pass is `str(v1 + v2) == 'Vector: [3, 5, 7]'` however it's returning `'Vector: [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3]'`

Comment: You are doing a list concatenation with operator `+` instead of an addition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python element-wise tuple operations like sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497885/python-element-wise-tuple-operations-like-sum)

Comment: Unless you are defining `__len__` and `__getitem__` for your class, you almost certainly want to be working with `self.v` and `other.v`, not `self` and `other` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, v):
        if len(v)==0: self.v = (0,0)
        else: self.v = v
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector '+' '.join([str(v) for v in self.v])
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(list([a + b for a, b in zip(self.v, other.v)]))
v1=Vector((1,2,3))
v2=Vector((4,5,6))
str(v1+v2)
```